# Iron Router: pathFor: I want to generate a url from a map

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a navbar widget that is generating links for top level navigation.

When the set of pages are for alliance leaders the iron-router paths look like :

```
'/alliance/:allianceId/players'
```

for the regular players looking at the regular player navbar the iron-router paths like:

```
'/player/:playerId/inventory'
```

I want the navbar to not care what the route parameters are. I want the navbar template to just take a map of values

```
<template name="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> <!--   -->
        <ul class="admin-tabs">
            {{#each routes}}
                <li class="{{tabActiveClass}}"><a href="{{pathFor pageName data=data}}">
                    <i class="glyphicon {{additionalClass}}"></i>&nbsp; {{displayName}}</a>
                </li>
            {{/each}}
            <li>
                {{> loginButtons}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</template>
```

with the

```
_.extend(Template.navbar, {
    ...
    data: function() {
        var routeController = Router.current(true);
        if ( routeController == null){
            return void(0);
        } else {
            debugger;
            return routeController.params;
        }
    },

    ...
});
```

However, this is not working. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should either wrap your code:

```
{{#with data}}
  ...
{{/with}}
```

or use `params=data` instead of `data=data`.